How to delete an entire package from a DevOps feed?
We have a Auzre DevOps server with published artifacts in several feeds.
Over time, we've accumulated packages that have been incorrectly published to the wrong feed, or test packages.
I need to clean these up and remove them.
I've seen plenty of posts on how to remove an individual package version, but this appears to leave the package in the feed still, with the version number shown with a line through it.
How do I purge the package entirely?

Note, that I do not want to "Hide deleted package versions". I want to delete them entirely.

Hi @midspace, have you enabled Hide deleted package versions option in your feed settings? Did it work for you?

To delete an entire package from a DevOps feed, go to your target feed -> click your target package -> Versions -> Select all version -> More actions -> Delete -> Delete.

Then refresh your browser, the package will disappear from the feed. If you want to permanently delete it, go to Recycle Bin -> Empty Recycle Bin.


Update
Go to your feed -> Feed settings -> Enable Hide deleted package versions



That is what I tried before posting this. The packages are still there after refreshing the browser. It does not disappear from the feed.

Try to use REST API NuGet - Delete Package Version to delete the package and check if it works.  If it still doesn't work, please run NuGet - Get Package Version and check what's the response.

It doesn't find that package version. It's the same response for a non-existent version.
{
"$id": "1",
"innerException": null,
"message": "Can't find the package 'PackageA' with version '1.3.0' in feed 'release'.",
"typeName": "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Packaging.Shared.WebApi.Exceptions.PackageNotFoundException, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Packaging.Shared.WebApi",
"typeKey": "PackageNotFoundException",
"errorCode": 0,
"eventId": 3000
}


Please try to clear the cache of your browser and check if it works. 2. Use different browsers to access your artifact. 3. What's the version of your Server? Go to your Azure DevOps Server Administration Console -> Application Tier. You can see it from version. It's like 19.225.34309.2 (AzureDevOps2022.1).


We're running version 18.181.32404.7 (Azure DevOps Server 2020 Update 1.2)


Have you tried to clear the cache of your browser? Did it work for you? If there is the same issue when using different browsers? I want to know if it's related to your browser or your collection itself. 2. According to your screenshot, the packages are old. You can publish a new package and check if there is the same issue or not to narrow down the issue.


I've gone through it with Chrome and Edge, and different packages. There's no caching on the browser and no proxy. I can delete a specific version, but not the empty package itself. The Azure DevOps API does not seem to have a command for deleting the package without specifying a version.

@midspace, The deleted package versions are shown by default as a reminder that the version number is taken and can't be published again. Please enable Hide deleted package versions option in your feed settings and check if it works. I have updated the steps above.
